# Testing chars and ints within a char variable

Tags: c

I'm having trouble finding out how to set up a loop where i enter input and then
stop the input by pressing 'e' or 'E'. The input entered is integers but needs to be stopped with a character. That is where i get lost. I have seen a bunch of information about using ascii conversions but i dont know how efficient that would be. This code is broken but it is as far as i could get. Any information would be helpful.

```
int main(void)
{
    char num;
    int sub;

    while (sub != 'e' || sub != 'E') {
        scanf("%d", &num);
        sub = &num;
        printf("%d", num);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know int is the best for manipulating numbers but it cant accept chars or atleast not as far as i know

Comment: 1) Need initialize `sub` before use it. 2) `||` --> `&&` 3) `scanf("%d", &num);
    sub = &num;` --> `scanf(" %c",  &num); sub = num;`

Comment: Try [this](https://ideone.com/fViI8W)

Comment: `sub != 'e' || sub != 'E'` is always true. Did you mean `sub != 'e' && sub != 'E'`?

Comment: I see there is a whole class of you posting your question here, just after your prof told you so? There are many things wrong with your code, you'd better first look into other resources for getting help. Especially your prof would be good. Voting to close because this is too broad.

Comment: Any idea what `sub = &num;`  actually does/tries to do? In particular as opposed to `sub = num;`?

Comment: General rules about C.  #1 Don't use gets.  #2 Don't use scanf. You are violating rule number 2.

Comment: The first rule about C is to ask the compiler to give you all the warnings it can. `-Wall` or equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) {
    char c = getchar();
    int num;

    while (c != 'e' || c != 'E') {
         if (isdigit(c))
              num = c - '0';
         c = getchar();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But you don't have to use an ascii character as a way to stop input. You can use EOF which is -1. It is Ctrl-D on UNIX systems and Ctrl-Z on Windows.
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)

Comment: For this `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)` to work `c` *needs* to be an `int`.

Comment: Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

A direct way to distinguish between an input of `int`, `'e'` and , `'E'` is to read a *line* of user input with `fgets()` and then parse it.

```
#define LINE_SZ 80
char buf[LINE_SZ];

while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) && buf[0] != 'e' && buf[0] != 'E') {
  if (sscanf(buf, "%d", &num) != 1) {
    Handle_other_non_int_input();
  } 
  sub = &num;
  printf("%d", num);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, `(sub != 'e' || sub != 'E')` is always true. If `sub` can never be `e` and `E` at the same time.

Note that `sub` is an `int` and not an integer pointer (`int *`).
The line `sub = &num;` assigns `sub` with `num`'s address.

And the value of `sub` is used in the control expression of the `while` loop before it is initialised. `sub` has garbage value at that point which is indeterminate. You have to initalise it with some value before using it.

Do

```
int num, rv;
while( 1 )
{
    rv=scanf("%d", &num);
    if(rv==0)
    {
        if( (num=getchar())=='e' || num=='E' )
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            while(getchar()!='\n');
            continue;
        }
    }
    printf("\n%d", num);
}
```

A value is read into `num` by `scanf()` whose return value is stored in `rv`.

`scanf()` returns the number of successful assignments which in this case should be `1` if  an integer value was read into `num` since `%d` is the format specifier.

If `rv` is `1`, it is a number and is printed. Otherwise it could be a character which won't read by the `scanf()` and would remain unconsumed in the input buffer. The first byte of this data is read by the `getchar()` and if this is `e` or `E`, the loop is exited but otherwise the input buffer is cleared till a `\n` is encountered and the next iteration of the loop is done without going into the part where the printing takes place.